# Magento 2.1.7 Data Migration Tool - Exception in [step: EAV Step]

Tags: magento-2.1, eav, data-migration

> Migrating from 1.9.2.1 to 2.1.7 ce to ce

at around 58% ..

`Notice: Undefined index: dest in ..../vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Eav/InitialData.php on line 156`

This is line 156

`public function getAttributes($type)
    {
        return $this->attributes[$type];  <<<< HERE
    }`

Any clues how to work around this? 
Please.

Comment: can you please check the attribute Maegnto 1.9.1. I think  $type is get null or blank value

Comment: Thank you for responding but I need more information from you.
Where should I be looking for the attribute? 
Yes, obviously $type is undefined but is $this->attributes["dest"] referring to a particular column in a particular row in some particular table?

Comment: It looks like this (line 420 in Eav/Data.php is calling the getAttributes method & it can't resolve 'dest'  ??? 

     `$destinationRecords = $this->initialData->getAttributes('dest');`

Answer (score 1):

This issue came about as a result of not fully installing Magento 2 before doing the data migration step(s) 
Thanks to Kristof from Fooman in NZ for helping me through this.
He advised to ensure I was able to log in and access the admin backend of M2 before doing the data migration.
I did that & the migration has now gone much further